# smartgwt SelectItem with empty value

Tags: java, smartgwt

I have a SelectItem, that fetches data from database. I need to add an emptyField to my select Item.

My code looks like that, and that works great.

```
SelectItem editor = new SelectItem(...);    
editor.setOptionDataSource(new DataAllowableValuesDS('data id for database request'));
```

but after i've changed it to the code below, start_row and end_row fields in HttpServletRequest have been changed to "-1". How can I solve that?

```
SelectItem editor = new SelectItem(...);
editor.setAllowEmptyValue(true);
editor.setOptionDataSource(new DataAllowableValuesDS('data id for database request'));

public DataAllowableValuesDS(String id) {        
    DataSourceField nameField = new DataSourceTextField("name", null, 2000);
    nameField.setPrimaryKey(true);
    setFields(nameField);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `valueField (="name")` and `displayField` for the SelectItem?
Those attributes allow DataSource to map results to the SelectItem.

One thing I noticed in your code is, value passed to 'id' in DataAllowableValuesDS constructor is never used.

Also, results should have both key/value pair.

Try changing SelectItem and DataAllowableValuesDS as

```
SelectItem editor = new SelectItem(...);
editor.setAllowEmptyValue(true);
editor.setValueField("key");
editor.setDisplayField("value");

public DataAllowableValuesDS(String id) {        
    DataSourceField keyField = new DataSourceTextField("key", "Key");
    DataSourceField valueField = new DataSourceTextField("value", "Value");

    setFields(keyField, valueField);
}
```

Other options

- use a [DataArrivedHandler](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/SelectItem.html#addDataArrivedHandler%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.events.DataArrivedHandler%29) to add an empty value
- try sending the empty value as part of results from server side

Post your `DataAllowableValuesDS` code if possible.